# Download issues when trying to use My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a lot of issues with My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile command. I want my application to download a file from internet. First, I tried to upload the file to dropbox and I copied the link. My application should download that file, but it gave an error like this: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. How do I bypass this error? After this, I tried to copy a link from an antivirus website and coded my program to download that file. It worked. Why this command works on a random link but not in dropbox files?

Also, I tried to upload that file to Google Drive. It didn't give me any error; the file was downloaded but it was 0 KB! It just downloaded a blank file. I tried another online file upload web site, but my application gave me an error like this: **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.** How do I fix these issues? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: Cloud storage like Dropbox and Google Drive have very specific authentication procedures you need to follow which I’d beyond the scope of the downloadfile method.  Bothe theses platforms have pretty well documented API services

Comment: As you're using a very old version of VS, I guess that the .NET version it's using could be too old to use a recent-enough version of TLS: "[Starting April 13, 2022, the Dropbox API requires calls to use TLS 1.2 or higher. After that date, calls using TLS 1.0 and 1.1 will no longer be supported.](https://help.dropbox.com/account-access/active-directory-connector)". So, with another guess, the whole of Dropbox may require TLS 1.2 or later. *If* that is the case then you'll need to use a later version of .NET, and preferably a later version of VS.